# Automatically update embedded Google Sheets Chart in Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, auto-update

I have inserted a chart into a Google Doc, but would like to make it update automatically instead of having to manually open the Doc and press the floating update buttons.

So far I have found no way to do this beyond writing a script to replace each one every time - which I have not yet felt strong enough to do.

How can an embedded chart be updated automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I found several answers from [this forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/ZRpghByKHNM) you might want to try:

Using XML Gadget for Charting:Steps if you would like to try out;

1. Go to your google spreadsheet (or googgle form data).
2. go to Menu>Insert>Gadget
3. click "chart" & select chart you like & "add to spreadsheet"
4. key-in all the chart setting required by the Gadget
5. click "apply & close"
6. After the chart populated, point your mouse to the left corner of chart, click "gadget"
7. You'll see "Get Query data source"-item a 
   and "Get XML" - item b
8. click the item b, example "http://www.google.com/ig/modules/image-bar-chart.xml"
9. Go to google "site" and "insert" > "more gadget"> "add gadget by url"> paste the item b, http://www.google.com/ig/modules/image-bar-chart.xml
10. You'll need to provide the data source in the pop-up windows, paste the link of item a and key-in all necessary setting. (refresh interval 1, 5, 30mins- set here)
11. save & done.

Using ARRAYFORMULA to make sure that the charts would be updated with the new information. Sample is in [this site](http://bunkaseminar.blogspot.com/2010/12/sample-questionnaire.html).

I'm not entirely sure if this is useful but since you're doing scripting, you might as well check Read and write data in [Firebase from Apps Script](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/read-and-write-data-in-firebase-from-apps-script).

Comment: Thanks - the problem with the gadget method is that it seems Google's timed triggers can be unreliable. I have some Scripts that run on timed triggers and I get an inbox full of failure logs every night.

Answer (score 1):

Google Docs doesn't support the proper way of linking and embedding objects like MS Office does. I haven't seen any real solution as yet.

Answer (score 0):

Found a hint at [github](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-sheets/issues/11):

> Yes, that is correct, published charts in Google Sheets only update 5 minutes after a change was made.