# Google apps script: How to make the script update embedded charts in Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

It's my first time trying out apps script, so bear with me.
I'm trying to automate creation of a report from a google sheet/spreadsheet through Google docs and save it as a PDF. Meaning the Docs works as a template for the values that are inputted through the spreadsheet. I've managed to get text to be updates automatically from Sheets to Docs every time the values change (and I run the script), aswell as save the Docs as a PDF and delete the Docs afterwards.
There are 5 charts in the spreadsheet that are embedded into the docs. In the spreadsheet the charts change when new data are added, but I struggle with getting the charts to update similar to the text. The only workaround I've managed so far is to have the script make the document, separate out the last part of the script that makes a PDF and deletes the Docs, manually press "update" on the charts, and then run the script that makes PDF. I've tried to have the script make a chart from scratch each time, but have been unsuccessful at that making a script that runs.

UPDATE: A sample of the input would be a number generally between 20 and 80, that would be representeted with a dot with an equal Y-value in the chart. I've also added a picture of one of the charts. The 4 other charts are similar.
[image: sample chart]

I've tried to get this script to work, but have been unable to make it work. Link: [How to update the data range of an existing graph using app script? [Google Sheets]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60226171/how-to-update-the-data-range-of-an-existing-graph-using-app-script-google-shee)

I've also read this post about a similar issue: [Automatically update embedded Google Sheets Chart in Docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39069674/automatically-update-embedded-google-sheets-chart-in-docs)

Here is some of the code:

```
const sheetID = '--[Sheet ID, blanked out for security reasons]--';
const docID = '--[Docs ID, blanked out for security reasons]--';
const folderID = '--[Folder location, blanked out for security reasons]--';

function genRapport() {
  
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID).getSheetByName('Score summary);

  const temp = DriveApp.getFileById(docID);
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  
  const pID = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue(); //Cell for ID

  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy")

  const file = temp.makeCopy(folder).setName(pID );
  const doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
  const body = doc.getBody();
  body.replaceText('{{pID}}', pID );
  body.replaceText('{{date}}', date);
  body.replaceText('{{E score}}', sheet.getRange('AZ4').getValue()); // Replaces {E score} with actual score from spreadsheet.

  body.updateChart(); // <- this is where the issue is.

  doc.saveAndClose();
  const pdf = folder.createFile(doc.getAs(MimeType.PDF)).setName(pID+'.pdf'); // Generates PDF
  //file.setTrashed(true) //Deletes Docs-file
}
```

Comment: I found a similar post to your question 

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62794107/google-docs-linked-charts-refresh-with-api-or-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62794107/google-docs-linked-charts-refresh-with-api-or-apps-script) since the feature that you are looking for is not yet available in Google Docs you can submit a feature request.

Comment: First, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About your question, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike I've added a picture of the chart. Input values are generally between 20 and 80, and are representeted on the charts as dots with corresponding Y-values. It's these charts that I can't seem to update automatically.

Comment: @Serenity Thank you for clearing it up and pointing me to a workaround! Will give it a try :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill. And, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation, again.

Comment: `I've also read this post about a similar issue` Sorry, I'm confused - it doesn't sound "similar", it sounds identical. And you didn't mention whether any of the suggestions in the answer were productive. Would you please advise?